# Как преобразовать одномерный массив в двумерный?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Как преобразовать одномерный массив в двумерный так, чтобы в M[i] было только 2 элемента?

```
M = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] # начальное состояние массива


M = [                        # конечное состояние массива
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1]  
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
M = [M[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(M), 2)]
```

Comment: Лениво уже на такие вопросы отвечать. Наверняка ведь очередной дубль )